# Confusion with three forms of the same subordinate clause

Tags: subordinate-clauses

I've a  question about the formation of a sentence. There are three forms of the same sentence which I'm confused with.

> 1. This is your plan which is what I'm a part of.
> 2. This is your plan which is I'm a part of.
> 3. This is your plan which I'm a part of.

Can anyone explain which form is the correct one, and why?

Comment: They're all unacceptable, and there's no context, so please provide one. Maybe it should be "This is **that plan of yours that I'm involved in**" or "**This is your plan, and I'm involved in it**"? Maybe not. I can't tell what you want to say or why

Comment: @BillFranke 1 and 3 are grammatically correct but possibly not semantically.

Comment: @Mitch: Grammaticality is always trumped by semantics and idiomaticity. However, all require a comma before "which" because it can't be a synonym for "that" in these sentences. None is acceptable.

Comment: @Bill: try saying that (your first sentence) to John Lawler. In fact, have you a more famous name than (sorry) your own for the statement, so that it's hard for people to argue that it's not a trump?

Comment: @Edwin: No, I don't have a more famous name. My own is notorious in some quarters of the English-usage-maven world, however. If Prof Lawler disagrees with my claim (he'll have to see it, of course, & care enough to want to respond to it, & I can't guarantee that either condition will be met), then I'm sure I'll hear about it. I'll assume that if no one else is interested in persuading the community here that my claim is incorrect, that it's tacitly accepted if not overtly embraced.

Comment: @BillFranke: trumped? always? is? "Colorless green ideas..."?

Comment: @Mitch: Yes, even that one. It's grammatical, but it was created by a linguist to make the linguistic point that grammaticality is one thing & meaning another: Just because it's grammatical doesn't mean that it's "good" or idiomatic English. No sane person goes around saying things like "colorless green ideas..." without a specific reason. Why not? Because speaking grammatical nonsense doesn't communicate anything of value in everyday life, only mockery, insanity, or a technical (theoretical) point. Your question isn't an argument against my claim, only a "Gotcha!" attempt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a relative clause introduced by a relative pronoun, the pronoun substitutes for one of the main parts of the clause, either the subject or a complement of the verb. Let's look at these three relative clauses by "undoing" the substitution. We'll use **This** for the part that **which** stands for:

1. **which** is what I am a part of ...
   *Substituting **this** for **which** gives us* **This** is what I am a part of = What I am a part of is **this**. *That's a perfectly OK sentence, so this is grammatical.*
2. **which** is I'm a part of ...
   *Substituting **this** for **which** gives us* **This** is I am a part of. *A part of what? Of **this**? Moving **this** to the end gives us* is I am a part of this. *This doesn’t work: there’s an extra verb on the front. So this version is not grammatical.*
3. **which** I'm a part of ...
   *Substituting **this** for **which** gives us* **This** I am a part of = I am a part of **this**. *Once more, the sentence is OK, so this is grammatical.*

So 1 and 3 are both grammatical. Which one is “correct”?—that depends on what you’re trying to say. The purely propositional content of both is the same—“I am a part of this”—but they focus on different things, and arise in different contexts:

- **Which I’m part of** arises when your interlocutor is asking about the **plan**. It gives new information about the plan: “It’s not just your plan, it’s also the plan I’m part of.”
- **Which *is what* I’m part of** arises when your interlocutor is asking about **you**:

> HIM: Tell me, dibyendu, what is it you do? **What are you part of?**”
>   YOU: Well, sir, **this!**
>   HIM: What’s this?
>   YOU: It’s Your Plan, sir!
>   HIM: My plan?
>   YOU: This is Your Plan, which is **what I’m a part of!** And very proud to be so!
>   HIM: Oh. Well, dibyendu, it does you credit!
>   YOU: Thank you, sir!
>   
>   Whichever version suits, a comma should follow *plan*; bare *This is your plan* implies that your interlocutor has only one plan. For either clause to be restrictive and not require the comma you would have to say *This is the plan of yours which &c*.

Comment: Stoney, excellent, +1.